# how to set jdk 11 in maven ~/.m2/settings.xml

Tags: java

Now I want to using jdk 11 to compile my project, and I have already set the default java to java 11:

```
~/.m2 ⌚ 15:27:30
$ java -version                                                                                                                                                                              ‹ruby-2.7.2›
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9, mixed mode)
(base)
```

and add config in `~/.m2/settings.xml` file:

```
<profile>    
  <id>jdk-11</id>    
  <activation>    
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>    
  <jdk>11</jdk>    
  </activation>    
  <properties>    
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>    
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>    
    <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>11</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>    
  </properties>    
</profile>
```

but when I using this command to compile project:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/maven@3.5/3.5.4_1/bin/mvn install
```

shows error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project util: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/dolphin/source/dj/source/backend/scom-java-common/util/src/main/java/scom/java/common/mulitshed/ShedTask.java:[5,14] illegal reference to restricted type 'var'
[ERROR] /Users/dolphin/source/dj/source/backend/scom-java-common/util/src/main/java/scom/java/common/mulitshed/RedisLocker.java:[5,14] illegal reference to restricted type 'var'
[ERROR] /Users/dolphin/source/dj/source/backend/scom-java-common/util/src/main/java/scom/java/common/controller/MysqlCheckControllerTester.java:[5,14] illegal reference to restricted type 'var'
[ERROR] /Users/dolphin/source/dj/source/backend/scom-java-common/util/src/main/java/scom/java/common/ntest/NTestService.java:[5,14] illegal reference to restricted type 'var'
```

what should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: specify those in `<properties>` section instead of `profile`(the layer should be removed)

Comment: 亲，理论上settings.xml里激活的profiler的properties是可以生效的。你这为啥没生效，需要在pom.xml里再写一遍maven.compiler.target和maven.compiler.source，后来找到原因了吗？

Answer (score 1):

add this config:

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
```